# Embeber una pagina html entera dentro de un template de Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

Hola tengo un proyecto **Vue.js** con una estructura de rutas en una sola pagina(**SPA**) típica de los frameworks reactivos con un componente principal donde creo el nav y el footer y dentro la llamada a la ruta correspondiente con `<router-view></router-view>`
Lo que ocurre es que necesito introducir una pagina con código externo dentro del proyecto que no puedo mezclar con Vue.js porque tiene mucho css que es demasiado incompatible y extenso como para hacerlo funcionar junto. Por ello quería ver si se podía introducir dentro del propio template una llamada a una **pagina html entera externa**, lo que se suele hacer con Iframe.
Lo primero que prove fue el propio Iframe con una etiqueta simple:

```
<template>
<iframe src="htmlexterno.html"></iframe>
</template>
```

Pero no me funciono y por lo que he visto es porque parece ser que Iframe no es compatible con Vue.js
Entonces buscando en internet encontre este codigo:

```
<template>
<div v-html="varhtml"></div>
<template>
<script>
export default {
data: {
    varhtml: '<p>Loading...</p>'
},

ready() {
    this.$http.get('htmlexterno.html').then(response => {
        this.varhtml = response.data;
    });
}
}
</script>
```

Pero tampoco me funciona.
 
Después gracias la ayuda de un foro conseguí que me cargue urls de internet, pero htmlexterno.html es un proyecto local y no me funciona.

La último que hice es esto pero solo funciona si pongo una url de intenet(no local):

```
<template>
    <iframe :src="ruta"></iframe>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        ruta: 'htmlexterno.html'
    })
}
</script>
```

Agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que al final me funciono fue poner el archivo html fuera del proyecto principal como si proviniese de otra web.

```
<iframe src="../../../../webexterna/htmlexterno.html"></iframe>
```